# Ruby using variables in print statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code, which is called by selecting option 1 from the menu in my program:

```
def self.addModuleToScheme
=begin
Create an empty hash for the schemes
=end
 schemes = Hash.new()
=begin
Allow user to enter scheme names into a set of variables, and use each scheme name as a hash/ array of modules.
Then allow the user to enter the the modules for each scheme into each of the hashes

Create specific hash elements by using the following line:
schemes = {:scheme1 => scheme1variable, :scheme2 => scheme2variable}
=end

 puts "What is the name of the scheme that you would like to add a module to? "
 schemeName = gets
=begin
Need to use an if statement here to check whether or not the scheme already exists, if it doesn't, create it, if it does,
tell the user that it does.
=end
 if schemes.has_key?(schemeName)
   puts "This scheme has already been added "
 else
   schemes[@noOfModulesInScheme] = schemeName
 end

 @noOfModulesInScheme + 1
# moduleName.moduleScheme = schemeName

# Print to check that scheme has been added to system:
 if schemes.has_key?(schemeName)
   puts "@schemeName has been added to the system "
 end
```

Currently, when I run the code, the menu is displayed, and I select option 1, which is when this code is called. Then I am asked what is the name of the scheme I would like to add the module to. I type that in, and then the program exits.

What I would like to do, is have a printout telling me that the scheme that I have just entered has been added to the system, and for my program to then go on and ask me what module I would like to add to the scheme.

But I can't work out how to print the contents of a hash element within a sentance. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

If it's any help, this is the other class in my program (where the menu is printed from)

```
class Application
# To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
require './courseModules.rb'
def initialize
  mainMenu
end

=begin
  def navigateTo(what)
  what.new(v).display
  mainMenu
  end
=end

def mainMenu
  puts "What would you like to do?
      1: Add module to a scheme
      2: Remove module from a scheme
      3: Query modules
      4: Modify module
      5: Register a student on a scheme
      6: Remove a student from a scheme
      7: Register a student on a module
      8: Remove a student from a module"
  case gets.strip
    when "1"
      CourseModules.addModuleToScheme
    when "2"
      CourseModules.removeModuleFromScheme
    when "3"
      navigateTo CourseModules
    when "4"
      navigateTo CourseModules
    when "5"
      navigateTo Student
    when "6"
      navigateTo Student
    when "7"
      navigateTo Student
  end
end
Application.new
end
```

**Edit**

Ok, I've made the changes suggested, however, when I now run my program, I'm getting an error saying "undefined method 'add_module' for CourseModules: Class (NoMethodError).

This is despite the fact that I deleted the old method I had (called addModuleToScheme) from the class, then wrote the new one, updated the method call in the menu, and saved both classes. It seems like my menu is still trying to call the old method even though it's no longer there... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code -

1. Use of Un-Ruby style syntax in method names and variable names.
2. Usage of `=begin; comment; =end` even for single line comments is not nice. Personally I prefer to use # style even for multi-line comments.
3. Interchangeable use of local and instance variables. For example in the last line you search the hash keys for a local variable `schemeName` and in the subsequent `puts` you use an instance variable`@schemeName`, though I suspect you might be trying to achieve interpolation effect for which btw you need to use `"#{schemeName}"` instead of `"@schemeName"`

However that aside if I understood correctly what you want to achieve (i.e. create a hash of schemes with scheme as key and module as value) then try the following code. In this example I have assumed that you want to have a 1:1 relationship between scheme and module, however if you want to define multiple modules per scheme you can achieve that easily by adding another loop and replacing the string value of scheme with an array in the code below.

```
def add_module
    schemes = {}
    scheme_exists = false
    add_another_scheme = true
    while add_another_scheme
            print "Enter Scheme Name: "
            scheme_name = gets
            schemes.has_key?(scheme_name.chop) ? scheme_exists = true : scheme_exists = false

            if !scheme_exists
                    print "Enter Module Name: "
                    module_name = gets
                    schemes[scheme_name.chop] = module_name.chop
                    puts "Scheme #{scheme_name.chop} has been added to the system"
            else
                    scheme_exists = false
                    puts "This scheme has already been added"
            end

            print "Enter another scheme? "
            ask_user_if_would_like_to_add_another_scheme = gets
            if !(ask_user_if_would_like_to_add_another_scheme.chop == "Y" or ask_user_if_would_like_to_add_another_scheme.chop == "Yes")
                    add_another_scheme = false
            end
    end
    puts schemes
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. What you've done there sounds like it's exactly what I want- I've tried updating my code, and have also updated the method call in my menu to reflect the new method name- I now have `CourseModules.add_module` when the user selects option 1. However, I'm now getting an 'undefined method' error for add_module (NoMethodError) despite having renamed the method to this in my CourseModules class, and saving it. Any suggestions?

Comment: ah I think in CourseModules class you need to define add_module as the class method. Change `def add_module` to `def self.add_module` or `def CourseModules.add_module` and it should work